# Installing Python Qt4 on bluemix

Tags: python, pyqt, ibm-cloud

I am trying to run a webscraping application using bluemix and python. The webscrape needs to happen on javascript generated elements and so I am using a python script that makes use of the PyQt4 library. The script relies on these imports to work:

```
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from flask import Flask
import json
import lxml
```

For the Flask and lxml modules, I am simply adding them to the requirements.txt file in my bluemix python source folder. It is the PyQt4 library that is the troublesome one. It would seem that you cannot install this library using pip which is what i believe the requirements.txt relies on.

The installation instructions for this library are here:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html

Any suggestions on how to get this library running in my bluemix application?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the PyQt installation instructions?

If you need to use `requirements.txt` you can find a prepackaged python .whl for your environment [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4). You should be able to either put the url directly into your `requirements.txt` file, or for offline installation, download the .whl to your system and specify its location instead.

[An example `requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt help for installing the library on a bluemix application. The prepackaged .whl files at that link are only for windows and i know that my bluemix server runs on ubuntu. 

The PyQt installation instructions also dont help much for an install onto bluemix.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to consider those files were Windows only. Sorry, I'm not familiar with bluemix, but if you're running ubuntu, can you not just run `sudo apt-get install python-qt4` (`python3-pyqt4` if you're running python 3)?

Comment: With bluemix i dont have access to the underlying linux server to run install commands.. so no not easily i dont think

Comment: That certainly doesn't make things easy. Since you only want Qt4, what about using PySide instead? You should be able to install that the usual way through pip/requirements.txt